# Can I ask a question realted to my former boss behavior?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-topic-definition

I read the [topic section](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but still I'm not sure if the question would be on topic.

Basically, I would like to ask for advice about a behavior of my former boss. He is currently doing something that I'm not comfortable with and I am not sure what to do.

Is that on topic?

Comment: Search first, to see if it has already been asked and answered. Otherwise, go for it!

Comment: If you want to make doubly sure you could post the body of the question you'd ask on Meta here first to gather feedback before you post it on the main site. That can give you some time to improve the question if it would be useful or necessary to make it on-topic. But you can also just post it and edit it on the fly as needed.

Comment: Just make sure there is something actionable and it’s not just a gripe. “My boss did this I hate that don’t you hate it too” will get closed.  “How do I achieve X goal when faced with behavior Y from my boss” is on topic.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say post it.

Obviously the nature of the behaviour may or may not make it suitable.

Just two examples:

- Ex-Boss withholding final paycheck - probably workplace
- Ex-Boss is stalking me - probably not workplace

Worst thing is the question gets closed. You will not get censured for posting in this type of grey area.